# How can I add second click to the same div?

Tags: javascript

I have two boxes. I want to create functions, which will give me some capabilities.

1. If I click on the black box the red one is shown.
2. When I click one black box again, I want to hide the red box.

This is what I have done:

```js
var showMeRedBox = document.getElementsByClassName('box2_red')[0]
var blackBox = document.getElementsByClassName('box1_black')[0]
var redBox = document.getElementsByClassName('box1_black')[0]
var hideRedBox = document.getElementsByClassName('box2_red')[0]



var showMe = function(show) {
  showMeRedBox.style.display = show
}
blackBox.onclick = function() {
  showMe('inline-flex');
}



var hideMe = function(hide) {
  hideRedBox.style.display = hide
}
blackBox.click = function() { // here should be seocnd click, when I want to hide the red box
  hideMe('none');
}
```

Do somebody give me advice, how can I do that? 
Thank you, 
Megi

Comment: The `click` handler only accepts one event, by creating a second, you are overwriting the initial click handler. `addEventListener` allows multiple events assigned, however, you only need one click here. Click, check the color, and show the proper box. Click again, do the same thing. Let the logic do the extra click handler for you

Comment: At a high level, what you want isn't to "create a second click".  What you want is to have a *single* click handler (which you have) and, within that handler, check the current state of the target element and modify that state accordingly.  So basically "if the red box is shown, hide it, else, show it".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to save the state of the redBox and then inside click ask for it:

```
var isHidden = false;
blackBox.click = function() {
    if (isHidden) {
       isHidden = false;//show the box
    } else {
       isHidden = true;
       hideMe('none');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX if you're familiar with

Refer AJAX part of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJesac0_Ftw

Hope it helps